# What mean ref in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, ref

I have traveled [the mongoose's docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#setting-populated-fields) but they don't provide deep explanation AFAIK:

here a snippet with the `ref` element:

```
 author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }
```

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: There is an explanation given based on another use case – `stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]`… "*Our `Person` model has its `stories` field set to an array of `ObjectId`s. **The `ref` option is what tells Mongoose which model to use during population**, in our case the `Story` model. All `_id`s we store here must be document `_id`s from the `Story` model.*"

Answer (score 1):

It stands for **Reference**. The value, in your case `Person` is the model it references. It means that the author is of type `Person`